# Pyspark version of Amazon Deequ

Tags: apache-spark, aws-glue, pyspark, amazon-deequ

I am working on AWS Glue and leveraging pyspark API for my ETL.
I believe if I need to use Amazon Deequ I need to switch to Scala. However I still want contine to use Pyspark APIs. Is there a way out?
If yes what are the steps I need to follow in AWS Glue?

Thanks

Comment: Are you already tried with Panda's Profiling? https://pypi.org/project/pandas-profiling/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Python wrapper for Deequ, called [PyDeequ](https://github.com/margitaii/pydeequ), it should work, although I haven't used it myself.

If you want to use Python, I would recommend to look to the [Great Expectations library](https://greatexpectations.io/) that implements functionality quite similar to the Deequ, including support for PySpark.

Comment: Thanks Alex. PyDeequ claims to have basic functionality and does not cover all features. Great Expectations Library seems to be using pure python however I would like to stick to pyspark as I have good volume of data

Comment: It supports Spark as well

Comment: The original Py Deequ will be merged with the official AWS Lab/python-deequ project.
https://github.com/awslabs/python-deequ